# Find Distance Function from Acceleration Function

Tags: calculus, physics, kinematics

The (non-constant) acceleration as a function of time, $a(t)$, is defined and known over $[t_0, t_2]$. It is also known that $a(t)$ is integrable. Also, $a(t)=\frac{dv(t)}{dt}$ and $v(t)=\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$, where $v(t)$ is the velocity function and $x(t)$ is the distance function. $t_1$ is a known time within $[t_0, t_2]$. Given $v(t_1)$ and $x(t_1)$, is it possible to find $x(t)$ over the entire interval? If so, how can this be done? Rigor would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$
v(t)-v(t_1)=\int_{t_1}^{t}a(s)\ ds.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\begin{align*}
x(t)-x(t_1)&=\int_{t_1}^t v(s)\ ds\\
&=\int_{t_1}^t\left(v(t_1)+\int_{t_1}^{s}a(u)\ du\right)\ ds\\
&= (t-t_1)v(t_1)+\int_{t_1}^t\int_{t_1}^{s}a(u)\ du\ ds.
\end{align*}
$$
Rearranging yields the solution
$$
x(t)=x(t_1)+(t-t_1)v(t_1)+\int_{t_1}^t\int_{t_1}^{s}a(u)\ du\ ds,\qquad t\in [t_0,t_2]
$$

Comment: Thanks @pre-kidney for the derivation! To generalize the result slightly, the conditions for velocity and distance can be prescribed at different times (instead of at the same time $t_1$), and we can still determine $x(t)$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I just realized this problem is a simple second-order differential equation, $\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=a(t)$ with two conditions given, and this method can be used to solve any such equation.

Comment: Yes, and the same method also solves $\frac{d^nx}{dt^n}=a(t)$.