# Effective Acceleration for Non-Constant Acceleration Motion

Tags: calculus, physics, mathematical-physics, kinematics

This question uses the same symbols as ["Effective Acceleration" is Distance-Averaged Acceleration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114568/effective-acceleration-is-distance-averaged-acceleration).

One of the kinematics formulas for constant acceleration is:
$\Delta x=v_0*\Delta t+\frac{1}{2}a\Delta t^2$.

Now, in a scenario of non-constant acceleration, given $v_0$, $\Delta x$, and $\Delta t$, we can find an effective acceleration $a_{eff}$ by solving
$\Delta x=v_0*\Delta t+\frac{1}{2}a_{eff}\Delta t^2$.

Is $a_{eff}$ an average of some kind? In particular, is it the time-averaged acceleration, distance-averaged acceleration, or neither?

I was not able to immediately determine the answer from the formula's derivation here:
[Find Distance Function from Acceleration Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110189/find-distance-function-from-acceleration-function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $v(t) = v_0 + \int_0^t a(\tau) d \tau$, we have
$x(t)-x_0 = \int_0^t v(\tau) d \tau = v_0 t + \int_0^t \int_0^\tau a(s) ds d \tau$.

Then the equivalent constant acceleration $a_\text{eff}$ that would produce the
same change of position is given by solving
$\int_0^t \int_0^\tau a_\text{eff}\, ds d \tau = {1 \over 2} a_\text{eff} t^2 = \int_0^t \int_0^\tau a(s) ds d \tau$.

Assuming that $a$ is integrable, we have
$\int_0^t \int_0^\tau a(s) ds d \tau= \int_0^t \int_s^t a(s) d \tau ds =
\int_0^t (t-s)a(s) ds $, so we see that
$a_\text{eff} = { \int_0^t (t-s)a(s) ds \over \int_0^t (t-s) ds} $
and we can interpret $a_\text{eff}$ as a weighted average of some sort.

Comment: In fact $a_\textrm{eff}$ is a time-averaged value weighted by the "time to go" (that is, the amount of time remaining before we have to mark the "final" position). For example, the amount of acceleration $10$ seconds before the end has ten times as much effect as the amount of acceleration $1$ second before the end, because the velocity change caused by the earlier acceleration has that much more time in which to change the particle's position.

Comment: A convolution of sorts...

Comment: I think it's also the first moment of $a(t)$ about $t$.